# How to Modify setInterval Code to Trigger the Interval Action Initially

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

Im not an JavaScript expert but I found a script which will help me accomplish what I need, however I need a small modification on it. Here is JS code:

```
$('html').addClass('js');

$(function() {

  var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 4000);

  var counter = 0;

  function showDiv() {
    if (counter ==0) { counter++; return; }

    $('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4')
      .stop()
      .hide()
      .filter( function() { return this.id.match('div' + counter); })   
      .show('fast');
    counter == 4? counter = 0 : counter++; 

  }

});
```

and here is an html code:

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='div1' class='display' style="background-color: red;"> 
  div1
</div>

<div id='div2' class='display' style="background-color: green;"> 
  div2
</div>

<div id='div3' class='display' style="background-color: blue;"> 
  div3
</div>
<div id='div4' class='display' style="background-color: yellow;"> 
  div4
</div>
<div>
```

now what this script do is make first div showup 10 seconds after page opens and then close it and open next one. What I need to change is to remove that 10 seconds time interval for first div so it open with the page and leave that time interval for other divs as it is. I hope you understand what Im trying to accomplish. Thanks for help.

Comment: Small mistake but you have `<div id="container">` and at the bottom `<div>` when it should be `</div>`. I'm guessing it was just a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: thanks for letting me know about this, didnt notice that div was not closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call `showdiv()` manually the first time, above where you set the timer and move the counter initialization above it:

```
...
var counter = 1;
showDiv();
var timer = setInterval( showDiv, 4000);
...
```

Comment: tried but its not working, its not showing first one when page loads but after 4 seconds, this only lowered the time for first one as much as i notice

Comment: Yes, because it's actually skiping the first iteration as I notice now. It lowered the time for the first, because before the time was 8 seconds for the first. Could you try to initialize counter with 1? I've also updated the example.

Comment: Problem here is your counter var blocking the first executiom ( the manual invoke )

Comment: Glad it solved the problem Boris - you can even accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following solution:

```
showDiv();
var timer = setInterval(showDiv, 4000);

var counter = 1;
function showDiv(){
  $('.display').hide();
  $('#div'+counter).show();
  (counter == 4 ? counter = 1 : counter++)
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3cKJV/**

You can also utilize the jQuery functions animate() or fadeIn() to apply an effect to the transition.

Comment: Yes, and that () will stop the setInterval from working, as showDiv doesn't return a function..

Comment: This won't work. You have to pass a functon pointer, not the execution of a function.

Comment: I plea the 5th lol...very long day.  I've updated to a working solution. Unless I missed something yet again.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your first div is visible from the beginning using css.
In your javascript do setInterval as you initially programmed.
Start your counter as 1.
In showDiv raise it. Drop the initial check where you return.
For the rest this should work. Get back to me if it doesn't.
I'll write the actual code on my pc tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, you could do it by CSS, but then you won't get the first animation.

Comment: ow yes, true! I guess I was a little too quick on my response.